# Implement "on losing focus" effect for any view in Android

Tags: android, onclick

I have a button and many other view components on an activity. I want to hide the button when I click any other places on the screen (like the button is losing focus). So I use

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/bg_page"
    android:onClick="randomClick" >
  <Button
    android:id="@+id/button_to_hide" />
  <ImageView
    android:onClick="zoomView"
    android:src="..." />
</RelativeLayout>
```

In the Java codes,

```
public void randomClick(View v){
   if(btn_to_hide.getVisibility()==View.VISIBLE){
      btn_to_hide.setVisibility(View.GONE);
   }
}

public void zoomView(View v){
   Intent intent = new Intent(...); //go to another Activity to zoom view the image
}
```

The problem is that

(1) When I happen to click to the `ImageView` which has an `onClick` listener, the `onClick` listener will be triggered which goes to another activity. I don't want to go to zoom view Activity yet as the I want to hide the button first. And the `ImageView` is just an example, there are many other clickable views so I don't want to change the functions like `zoomView()` one by one.

(2) A minor problem is that although I set "`match_parent`" to the main layout, when I click the bottom part of the screen, the button is not hide? (The content is not taking the full height of the screen)

Comment: bind the click listener to your main layout

Answer (score 1):

i made a sample for this ..check this..may be it help you

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener {

RelativeLayout layout;
Button btnClick;
ImageView imageClick;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    layout = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.layout);

    btnClick = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
    imageClick = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView);

    layout.setOnClickListener(this);
    btnClick.setOnClickListener(this);
    imageClick.setOnClickListener(this);
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    switch (v.getId()) {
    case R.id.layout:

        if (btnClick.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE) {
            btnClick.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        } else if (btnClick.getVisibility() == View.INVISIBLE) {
            btnClick.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }

        break;
    case R.id.button:
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Click Button",
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        break;
    case R.id.imageView:
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Click Imageview",
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        break;

    default:
        break;
    }
}
```

}

and xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/layout"
android:clickable="true"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".MainActivity" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:text="@string/hello_world" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dip"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/imageView"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dip"
    android:text="Click" />
```

Edit:
change your xml with this

add  android:clickable="true" in your layout.

Comment: try this..may be it will help you to solve your problem

Comment: Great thanks! Binding to the main layout is a promising way. I still have some problems as edited. I'll look into those now (especially some views are dynamically created and I may have no IDs for them).

Answer (score 0):

For your first question,

Check if button is hidden first than start the activity.

```
public void zoomView(View v){
   if( btn_to_hide.getVisibility()==View.VISIBLE)
         return;
   Intent intent = new Intent(...); //go to another Activity to zoom view the image
}
```

You have to be sure `zoomView` method called before `randomClick`. Or better add a fade out effect to the button in `randomClick` instead hiding it right away.

Comment: What is the inherent mechanism in calling sequence on parents' and children's event listeners? zoomView is just one function, and there could be many, I don't want to check btn_to_hide visibility in each functions.

Comment: @mrmoment depends on the layout. Your best bet is adding your button in a layout that overlays main content.Overlay layout's width and height should be same with the main content. That way your overlay layout handles click first and you can hide it instead of hiding button